# How to make VLC click through

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, vlc

I have been all over the web looking for a solution to this problem!

I'm looking for a way to make my VLC window "click through" on linux.

I have found some python code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917174/3426514 that says it can solve the problem, but I dont know how to apply that answer to my VLC window.

Is there a way to make a bash script that i can execute after vlc has started that will make the vlc window click-through? Or anything else, like a CCM plugin or a vlc plugin or magic foo?

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 if that is helpful :)

Edit: Another implemetation, part of the notifications code: 
https://github.com/dkasak/notify-osd-customizable/blob/master/src/bubble.c#L1608

Edit2: A SVG Implementation, dont think this applies, but it is kinda relevant https://superuser.com/questions/699289/making-cairo-clock-click-through-able-cairo-graphics

Edit3: The used to be a compiz plugin called ghost a long long time ago https://github.com/compiz-reloaded/compiz-plugins-experimental

Edit4: To address the downvote to close: I expect the actual code to do this would be a few lines at most, i just have no clue how to do it. If there is something that I can provide to narrow the focus or provide more information, I will gladly do so.

Edit 5: Another related question. [Create a click through window for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670032/create-a-click-through-window-for-linux?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: VLC writes directly to the video buffer unless you specify a different method, and handles whatever clicks are going on inside it's window. There is no "pass through" unless you're using a wrapper that handles this. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have limited screen real estate, and i'm doing some programming that uses my whole screen. I would like to watch a video while working, but still be able to click the controls on the programming window behind the video. With transparency I can easily set things up so i can see both the video and the work nicely, but I need a way to click "behind" the video

Comment: Essentially I want a video playing window that besides from playing the video "is not there" for the purposes of working with the pc

Comment: I think that ghost thing linked above is the closest to what I need, but .. help ! :D

Comment: You can have VLC write to the desktop background, then set all your app windows to be partially transparent. Output to Background is a VLC option. What you want is backwards from that, where VLC is overlayed on top of everything else, but ignored for user input.

Comment: thats  a good option, do you know if that works in ubuntu?

Comment: if you can upgrade that comment to an answer, i can at least upvote it :)

Comment: Done! And yes, it should work in Ubuntu. I know it works in Fedora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have VLC write to the desktop background, then set all your app windows to be partially transparent. Output to Background is a VLC option. What you want is backwards from that, where VLC is overlayed on top of everything else, but ignored for user input, however if you don't mind going the other way, it's "already in there" 8-)

Comment: although its not exactly what I asked for, this achieves the same effect.